# Can we use React-Native library in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, web-applications, libraries

I'm a mobile developer and new to web development. Can we use **react-native libraries in reactjs?** Also the reason for this is, I'm looking for segment-control tab similar to iOS, [this one](https://github.com/react-native-community/segmented-control). Drop some links or references if you know!
Thanks,

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use react-native packages in plain old react. However, these shouldn't be too hard to implement / translate (after all react-native and react are very similar swap the `<View>` tags with `<div>` tags etc. This is oversimplifying it but you get my point.)

Also if you are simply porting a react-native app to web you could be interested in react-native-web (supported by expo for example)